# Weird Log Output In PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

Everytime I do something in my `PhpMyAdmin` installation, there is a strange output at the bottom that I cannot seem to get rid of. The first line always starts out something like:

```
9 queries executed 9 times in 0.0026915073394775 seconds
```

or

```
3 queries executed 3 times in 0.00045561790466309 seconds
```

or something similar which is followed by a multi-dimensional array, displayed, containing information about the queries. This always happens: even when just clicking through the various areas and not actually performing any inputted queries to MySQL.

Does anyone know what this is? or more importantly, how to turn it off?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: at a guess there is some debugging setting in the config

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Dagon's nudge in the right direction, I was finally able to find where this setting was. In the root directory of the `PhpMyAdmin` installation is a file titled `config.inc.php`. Inside this configuration file is a variable:

```
$cfg['DBG']['sql'] = true;
```

Setting this to false helped the situation along with the setting in the `PhpMyAdmin` GUI. To find that setting, from the main screen go to `Settings`, then `Features`, then `Developer`, and then make sure that `Debug SQL` is unchecked.

Simply modifying only one of these did not work. I had to change both before I was finally able to get rid of that debugging output.